# Set left-right audio balance

Tags: audio, headphones

My earphones took an unexpected trip through the wash today and now the right earbud is a little quiet. I used to own an iPhone and under the accessibility settings, one could change the Left-Right volume balance. I can't seem to find a setting like that. Is there an app I can use?

I have a Samsung Galaxy S II X (t989) with Cyanogenmod 10.1.

Answer (score 2):

What I did -- and my problem is an ear that doesn't work properly rather than an earbud that's been washed too often -- was to shell out for [Poweramp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxmpz.audioplayer) which has built in balance controls along with its rather elaborate tone controls and equaliser. Well worth the money for solving this problem.

Comment: Does Poweramp's equaliser work with other apps? I use Google Play Music and have all my music stored there. I'm not willing to change players.

Comment: I don't know. Haven't tried it.